# I can not change current path in c, visual studio

Tags: c, file, path, visual-studio-2015

I am working on an application in C, using Visual Studio 2015 for getting the files from a path.

Idea is that I run the application and I write the command: `list path`.

The application should go at that path and list me all the files from there. All is fine, but I need to save the files in a text file which should be in the project folder.

My problem is that I can't go back from the path I write in command to project path.

For example, I have project in `C:\\Visual Studio\\projects\\application`, and I want to create the text file here, but when I write from my keyboard in console that path, for example: `list C:\\MinGWStudio`, the text file will be create there.

The code:

```
printf("Comanda a fost executata cu succes!\n");
SetCurrentDirectory(argv[0]);
FILE *outFile;
outFile = fopen("list.txt", "w+");
printf("%s\n", lista->cale);
fprintf(outFile, "%s\n", lista->cale);
```

Comment: Please check `argv[0]`, it's not what you apparently think it is. Always check the return value of `fopen()`, you might not have permissions in the target directory and it would fail.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does char \* argv\[\] means?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16666353/what-does-char-argv-means)

Answer (score 0):

Apparently you want

```
SetCurrentDirectory(argv[1]);
/*                       ^ 1 not 0 */
```

`argv[0]` is the name of the current program, so it's not a directory. Also, I don't know if or what `SetCurrentDirectory()` returns, but if I was the API designer, surely I would make it return something that would inform the caller about failure or success.

Comment: @SebiBurchi - if argv[1] is null then you have no command line arguments - see the comments in your post